# Добавить класс active, если элемент кликнут

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят привет. Возник вопрос. У меня есть меню, по клику он скролит меня до секции. И мне нужно, например, чтобы если я сам, мышкой проскролил до определенной секции, то он искал в меню класс, который отвечает за эту секцию и красил его в красный. Надеюсь нормально объяснил.

```js
$(window).on('scroll',function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 50) {
        $(".menu-nav-header").addClass("anim-scroll");
    } else {
        $(".menu-nav-header").removeClass("anim-scroll");
    }
});
</script>
<script>


 $('a.scrollTo').on('click', function(){
  
  // data-scrollTo = section scrolling to name
  var scrollTo = $(this).attr('data-scrollTo');
  
  
 

   $( "a.threeHr" ).each(function() {
    if(scrollTo == $(this).attr('data-scrollTo')){
     
      $("hr").css('marginLeft', '77.5%');
    }else{
     
    }
  });

     $( "a.oneHr" ).each(function() {
    if(scrollTo == $(this).attr('data-scrollTo')){
     
      $("hr").css('marginLeft', '10%');
    }else{
     
    }
  });
$( "a.twoHr" ).each(function() {
    if(scrollTo == $(this).attr('data-scrollTo')){
     
      $("hr").css('marginLeft', '44%');
    }else{
     
    }
  });
 

  // animate and scroll to the sectin 
  $('body, html').animate({
    
    // the magic - scroll to section
    "scrollTop": $('#'+scrollTo).offset().top
  }, 1000 );
  return false;
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
}
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#main-header {
    background-image: url(../img/background2.jpg);
    min-height: 100%;max-width: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left center;
    background: black;
    overflow: auto;
} 
    .main-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: .5;
        z-index: 0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #34373a, #696c70);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, #34373a, #696c70);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #34373a, #696c70);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to left, #34373a, #696c70);
    }
        .header {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #headet-title {
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif;
        margin: 15% 0 0.5% 0;
font-size: 1.7em;
    }
    #description-header {
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;
}
.anim-scroll {
    background: black;
}
#menu-nav a {
    color: white;
      text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  width:120px;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  transition:all .33s linear;
  -webkit-transition:all .33s linear;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

.two:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 44%;
}

.three:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 77.5%;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


hr {
  height: .15rem;
  width: 12%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ff2a58;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.menu-nav-header {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
padding: 5px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#logo h2 {
color: white;
        font-family: 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif;
}
.button {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
.button a {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid;
padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
border-radius: 3px;
font-size: 1.3em;
}
.header-title-border {
height: 2px;
width: 190px;
background-color: #ff2a58;
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 1%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="scroll/section-scroll.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scroll/jquery.section-scroll.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Condensed" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="main-header">
  <div class="header"> 
    <div class="menu-nav-header">    <div id="logo">
      <h2>NAME</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a class="scrollTo oneHr" data-scrollTo="main-header" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li class="two"> <a class="scrollTo twoHr" data-scrollTo="content2" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li class="three"> <a class="scrollTo threeHr" data-scrollTo="content3" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
    <div id="headet-title">
      <h1 class="wow fadeInDown">Name of Your Company</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="header-title-border"></div>
    <div id="description-header">
    <span class="wow fadeInDown">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque voluptate commodi impedit, 
        vitae vero, quo et odit natus sequi odio reprehenderit expedita voluptatum aspernatur, dolore soluta corporis aliquid animi iure.</span>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <a href="#" class="button-a">Get Started</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<div id="content2" style="padding-top: 50%">sd</div>
<div id="content3">sddfgdsgdfgdg</div>
```

Comment: Вы хотите сделать это своими силами или bootstrap можно использовать?

Comment: @Axenow своими силами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если можно, я просто приведу свой код, который у меня уже используется. В целом он делает, что вам надо - позволяет скроллить вниз и пункты меню будут активироваться.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent hard jump, the default behavior

    var target = $(this).attr("href"); // Set the target as variable

    // perform animated scrolling by getting top-position of target-element and set it as scroll target
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 600, function() {
      location.hash = target; //attach the hash (#jumptarget) to the pageurl
    });

    return false;
  });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop();

  // Assign active class to nav links while scolling
  $('.page-section').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).position().top <= scrollDistance) {
      $('.menu a.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.menu a').eq(i).addClass('active');
    }
  });
}).scroll();
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 64px;
}

.page-section {
  height: 480px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 3em;
  background: blue;
  color: yellow;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu_item {
  display: block;
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.menu_item:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.menu_item.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<nav class="menu" id="mainNav">
   <a class="menu_item" href="#1">Section 1</a>
   <a class="menu_item" href="#2">Section 2</a>
   <a class="menu_item" href="#3">Section 3</a>
   <a class="menu_item" href="#4">Section 4</a>
    <a class="menu_item" href="#5">Section 5</a>
    <a class="menu_item" href="#6">Section 6</a>
    <a class="menu_item" href="#7">Section 7</a>
</nav>

<div class="page-section hero" id="1">
   <h1>Scrolling menu 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="2">
   <h1>Scrolling menu 2</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="3">
   <h1>Scrolling menu 3</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="4">
   <h1>Scrolling menu 4</h1>
</div>
```